multiple general solutions for this differential equation
In the differential equation below, one way to solve it is to replace y with cos(u) or sin(u). But, when I tried both cos(u) and sin(u), general solutions for y seem different. Is this expected or did I do something wrong?
$ y{}' = \sqrt{1-y^{^{2}}}$
By the way, I got the following answers.
When I replace y with sin(u), y=sin(x+c) where c is constant.
When I replace y with cos(u), y=cos(-x+c) where c is constant.

If you're confused, because you expected the general solutions to be unique, this is only guaranteed when the system is linear.

The constants in both solutions are not neecssarily the same. Shifting one by $\pi/2$ yields the other

$y=\sin(x+c_1)$ and $y=\cos(-x+c_2)$ is the same since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary.

Right. I made the wrong assumptions. Thank you so much for the clarification
